# jquery button close in new tab and new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, external

how can i make it so that whenever a person clicks on the the first button it opens in a new window also how can i make it so that when a user clicks the second button that it opens in the same tab or window. i want to achieve this with jquery that being said i don't want to write any inline javascript otherwise if that was the case i wouldn't have posted the question i know how to achieve this using inline javascript but i want to do it using external js file and jquery.

open in new window

```
    <button class="button cf-button preview-bt" role="button" type="button" href="#">
                        <span class="button-content"> Preview </span>
                <span class="button-icon"> </span>
    </button>
```

open in same window

open in new window

```
   <button class="button cf-button preview-bt" role="button" type="button" href="#">
                        <span class="button-content"> Preview </span>
                <span class="button-icon"> </span>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

for open in new window or tab :

```
$(".button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.open(this.href, '_blank');
});
```

for open in new popup window :

```
$(".button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.open(this.href, '', 'width=100%', 'height=100%');
});
```

for open in same window :

```
$(".button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.location=this.href;
});
```

Comment: everything works except for the script for open in same window that code does not work can you please provide me with an alternative code for jquery same window code

Comment: If you think this the solution, please mark it as an answer.


If you cant get it work, check your code again, may your class is missing or just remove this code `event.stopPropagation();`
You should get it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use jQuery for this. Instead, you can use something in the `<head>` tag like:

```
<base target="newWindow" />
```

### jQuery Alternate

```
$(".button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'newWindow');
});
```

Comment: however i want to use jquery also

Comment: also i have many a tags in the same page its only the buttons that i want to affect

Comment: Okay, in that case, you can use the code I updated in the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
​$( '#link' ).click( function( event ) {
    window.open( this.href, '_blank' );
    event.preventDefault();
});​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mobweb/LPcMp/

Comment: `_blank` opens a new tab each time; I think you mean another name.

Comment: also could you please show me how to open the link in the same window

Comment: now could you do the js fiddle thing again and show me how to open in the same page because i not using a tags im actually using buttons don't ask why i just chose to. please help me.